# Routing in QGIS with road restrictions layer - plugin search

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, routing

I'm looking for a simple way (without PGRouting atm) to show all possible road connections from a starting point. The effect should be a new layer showing all the possible road connections. Something like Road Graph but without stating the end point (every end of the road should be the end-point)

I have a small layer of county roads, there are no more than 100 possible routs in it.

Second thing are the road restrictions - a point layer where objects are snapped to the road layer. If there is a restriction, then this point on the road should be the end-point.

So finally I'm looking for a result that will show me all road connections restricted to encountered objects from a specified layer.

Do you know any plugin that could do something similar to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such core tool or plugin.

I'd recommend modifying the routing graph by actually breaking it at the restrictions.

Other solutions will require programming efforts.

Comment: By "modifying the routing graph" you mean making changes in Road Graph plugin or other tools? I don't see any settings like that

Comment: @crudeaxe No, I mean modifying the line layer that is used as input for the routing graph.